# is it possible to make a call back to an outer nested class in java?

Tags: java, android, callback, nested-class

here's an example of what I'm trying to do

```
 public class BookModel {

        private void update_method() {
            get_info task = new get_info(this)
            task.exicute(some args); 
        }

        public void finishedCallback(some_return_type result) {
        // do some stuff when finsiehd. 
        }


    class get_info extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, String>, Void, dataType>
    {
        private BookModel bookModel; 

        public get_info ( BookModel reset) {
            bookModel = reset; 
        }

        @Override
        protected dataType doInBackground(arg...)
                        some procscessing. 
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(dataType result) {
            bookModel.finishedCallback(result);
        }
    }
    }
```

How can i get this callback system to work... I tried using an inteface as well, but it did not work. I think it's because you need 3 classes with an interface (correct me if I'm wrong). also I'm open to any suggestions, but Ideally I would like to keep this functionality within the same class if possible. any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `you need 3 classes with an interface` where did you get that?

Comment: the declaration of your doInBackground is wrong. you need `protected getProductInfoBriefFull doInBackground(Void...) {`

Comment: @njzk2 well I'm kinda counting the interface as a class... so you need the interface, the class that emit's the signal and the class that that receives the signal... but if you don't count the interface as a class then you need only two... but the problem seems to be that this class is nested.

Comment: I was not able to figure out what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to access the BookModel instance from get_info, you simply write BookModel.this.finishedCallback(result)

Comment: @mrak, given that the class is not static, and there is no ambiguity (no finishedCallback in get_info) calling `finishedCallback` directly would work too.

Comment: thanks guys... I appreciate all the help. I'll give it a go.

Comment: @AlexW.H.B.BTW: you are Ruby programmer? In Java everything is CamelCase ;)

Comment: @mrak for the most part I write in PHP and python, however I have done a bit of ruby. I'm pretty new to java right now. thanks for the tip. I'll try to stick with camel case from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

this is worked for me.

```
 public class BookModel implements get_info.xyz {

    private void update_method() {
        get_info task = new get_info(this);
        task.exicute(some args); 
    }

    public void finishedCallback(String result) {
    // do some stuff when finsiehd. 
    }

 }
//----------------------------------
class get_info extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, String>, Void, dataType>
{


    private xyz bookModel; 
    public interface xyz
    {
       void finishedCallback(String str);
    }
    public get_info ( xyz reset) {
        bookModel = reset; 
    }

    @Override
    protected dataType doInBackground(arg...)
                    some procscessing. 
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(dataType result) {
        bookModel.finishedCallback(result);
    }
}
```